# SSL certificates and group policy

Tags: group-policy, ssl-certificate, certificate

We are in the process of rolling out a new website and want to secure the administrative parts with ssl/https. As we see it there is no reason to purchase an ssl certificate from a root CA since the administrative part is not to be seen by customers so we just want a (self-signed) ssl certificate to protect the communication.

To make the experience as nice as possible for in-house users we want to trust this certificate but instead of requiring all users to manually install the certificate we would like to push this certificate to all users using group policy (or something similar). Is that possible for a self signed certificate?

An additional question; we also have a testserver deployed inhouse and would like to secure that as well (the internal testserver will have an internal DNS/IP) but can we use the same selfsigned ssl certificate as we use on the public website or would we require a different one (which we then also could push out via group policy)

Hope the question makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

If all of your users are in AD and you have `AD Certificate Authority` (AD CA) installed on your DC then you can simply issue from your AD CA needed certificate, attach this certificate in IIS to your web site. 
As a result all of domain users will automatically trust issued certificate (with no manual or GPO installations).

About your second question: I recommend you to issue for your test server another certificate from the same AD CA.